# Home Theater: Projector + Soundbar: How to get audio in sync?

Tags: home-theater, projector

I have had a lot of issues with audio sync when using projectors. (The projector is slow to render the image, so if the audio is played directly from the digital source, it is early, and annoying!)

The setups I am seeing would have me send the HDMI signal to the soundbar FIRST, and then to the projector.

When I do this (or something like it) via a stereo, the audio is not in sync. Via the stereo, I have to take send HDMI to the projector, and then RCA cables back from the projector to the stereo.

THE QUESTION: If I go :

HDMI Source (media PC) -> HDMI -> Soundbar -> HDMI -> Projector

How do I handle audio sync?

Comment: How is your system set up now ? All components.  The projector should output both  video and audio at the same time.

Comment: is the audio simple stereo or multi-channel?  Is this for presentation or movie experience?  Does Projector have HDMI out?

Comment: Perhaps this may help. https://www.avsforum.com/forum/index.php

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thanks, I will post over at avsforum.  https://www.avsforum.com/forum/195-soundbars/3153444-projector-soundbar-how-get-audio-sync.html#post59799112